# Canvas on Chrome Mobile not working after rotation

Tags: html, google-chrome, canvas

Trying to fix a really annoying problem that I'm having. I have an HTML5 canvas that I'm allowing users to draw on, which is loaded in an iframe. When the page first loads, it checks to see if we're on a mobile device and, if so, it resizes the whole page, including the iframe. I then have a setTimeout that runs every few seconds to check and see if my canvas is a different size from the frame it's loaded in. If it's different, I change the canvas size and then reinitialize it (using Kineticjs 1.0, I know there are newer versions but we're not ready to upgrade).

This works in most of the mobile browsers that we test, but Chrome (on iOS and Android) doesn't allow drawing on the canvas either when the page is first loaded in portrait or after an orientation change. It just scrolls the page (standard touch event) and ignores all of my preventDefaults. I can't even get it to do an alert on touchstart after the orientation changes.

Has anyone run across this before? I'm thinking it's either something with the fact that the canvas itself is changing or that maybe once the new stage(canvas) is created in Kinetic all of the defined listeners become ignored.

**Update**:

Here's some of the code I'm dealing with:

```
// This page is loaded in a frame, so we check to see when the parent is loaded
parent.$(document).ready(function()
{
    $(document).ready(function() 
    {
        ut();
        setTimeout('start_orientation_detect_timer()','2000');
    });
});

function start_orientation_detect_timer()
{
    if(document.getElementById("data").value.length == 0 && Math.floor(canvas.width) != Math.floor(parent.$(parent.top_origin.frame_array['sig_block_frame']).width()) || Math.floor(canvas.height) != Math.floor(parent.$(parent.top_origin.frame_array['sig_block_frame']).height()))
    {
        if(top_origin.misc_variables.mobile_device !== false && top.window.orientation == 0)
        {
            parent.$('#flip_to_landscape_msg').show();
            parent.$('#flip_to_landscape_msg').effect("pulsate", { times:200 }, 2000);
        }
        else
        {
            parent.$('#flip_to_landscape_msg').stop(true, true);
            parent.$('#flip_to_landscape_msg').hide();
        }
        ut();
    }
    else
    {
        // so from this frame several deep, we need to know the orientation, which will only be in the top of the DOM
        if(document.getElementById("data").value.length == 0 && top_origin.misc_variables.mobile_device !== false && top.window.orientation == 0)
        {
            parent.$('#flip_to_landscape_msg').show();
            parent.$('#flip_to_landscape_msg').effect("pulsate", { times:200 }, 2000);
        }
        else
        {
            parent.$('#flip_to_landscape_msg').stop(true, true);
            parent.$('#flip_to_landscape_msg').hide();
        }
    }
    setTimeout('start_orientation_detect_timer()','2000');
}

function ut()
{
    canvas=document.getElementById("drawing_canvas");
    context = canvas.getContext("2d");
    //console.log(Math.floor(parent.$(parent.top_origin.frame_array['sig_block_frame']).width())+' '+Math.floor(canvas.width)+' '+Math.floor(parent.$(parent.top_origin.frame_array['sig_block_frame']).height())+' '+Math.floor(canvas.height));
    canvas.width = parent.$(parent.top_origin.frame_array['sig_block_frame']).width();
    document.getElementById('saved_layer').style.width = canvas.width;
    canvas.height = parent.$(parent.top_origin.frame_array['sig_block_frame']).height();
    document.getElementById('saved_layer').style.height = canvas.height;
    myStage = new Kinetic.Stage(canvas);

    canvas.onmousemove = function()
    {
        var mousePos = myStage.getMousePos();
        var mouseDown = myStage.getMouseDown();
        if (mousePos!=null && mouseDown)
        {
            draw_b(mousePos.x, mousePos.y);
        }
        else
        {
            new_segment = true;
        }
    };

    canvas.ontouchstart = function()
    {
        BlockMove(event);
    }

    canvas.ontouchmove = function()
    {
        var mousePos = myStage.getMousePos();
        console.log(mousePos);
        if (mousePos!=null)
        {
            draw_b(mousePos.x, mousePos.y);
        }
    };

    canvas.ontouchend = function()
    {
        new_segment = true;
    };

    myStage.listen();
}

function BlockMove(event)
{
    // Tell Safari not to move the window.
    event.preventDefault() ;
}
```

I know some of this isn't the most updated code, but it does work except for on Chrome mobile. I've gotten it to the point where if I do not call the start_orientation_detect_timer then the canvas is only about 100px wide by 210 tall, but I can draw on it in Chrome mobile. It seems that once the canvas is stretched, I can't draw anymore. Not even a larger canvas with bigger strokes, nothing happens and the touchstart isn't triggered.

Comment: Some code would help.

Comment: Sorry about that, I updated the original post with the code